# Backbone js: Only render when specific attributes have changed?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I know that in a backbone view you can bind to the change event to rerender like this:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
},
```

However is there a way to only render when specific attributes change? I.e. specify a whitelist (or blacklist) of attributes that should or shouldn't trigger a re-render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a whitelist of attributes you can do the following

```
var whitelist = ['att1', 'attr2'];
this.model('change', function(model){
    var hasChanged = function(attr) { //check if attr has changed
            return model.hasChanged(attr);
        };
    if(whitelist.some(hasChanged)) { //some attr has changed
       this.render();
    }
}, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Backbone also trigger a change event for each attribute when they change, in the form `change:attributeName`, so the following is what you want:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.model.bind('change:attributeName', this.render, this);
},
```

From [the docs:](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog)

> "change:[attribute]" (model, value, options) — when a specific attribute has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

you can specify only one attribute like this

```
change:attributeNmae
```

*example:*

```
this.model.bind('change:name', this.render, this);
```

render will be called only if name changes